# Jinja - displaying two different values in a for loop

Tags: flask, jinja2

My goal would be to display both the url path and image source at once for a table entry when iterating through a for loop. However, I am accessing the url for images and the path through two different keys. This returns an entry for the link and one for the image separately.

```
{% for node in dictionary_list %}
            {% for key, value in node.iteritems() %}
                    {% if key == 'image' %}
                        <td></td>
                        <td><img src={{ value }}></td>
                    {% elif key == 'path' %}
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href={{ "http://example.com"+value }}>Link</a></td>
```

I've thought of putting both the path and image in one key and parsing out each, but this doesn't seem feasible with Jinja. Would code that return something like the following be possible?

```
{% for node in dictionary_list %}
            {% for key, value in node.iteritems() %}
                    {% if key == 'image_link' %}
                        <td></td>
                        <td><a href={{value1}}><img src={{value2}}></a></td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your data structure. Best is to provide each value with a dictionary of both an `url` and `file_path` key to the image. I do not know the structure nor the depth of your original `dictionary_list` so this is a best guess, but you could do something like this:

```
dictionary_list = {'node_name_1': {'url': 'some-image.jpg', 'file_path':'/image/path'},
                   'node_name_2': {'url': 'some-image.jpg', 'file_path':'/image/path'},
                    ... }
```

Then you could access them inside your Jinja2 loop as follows:

```
{% for key, value in dictionary_list.iteritems() %}
  <td><a href={{value['url']}}><img src={{value['file_path']}}></a></td>    
{% endfor %}
```